# Kernel code responsible for virtual momory

Tags: linux, kernel

I know 'even a single process can have a virtual address space larger than the system's physical memory' so Just want to know which kernel code is responsible to create virtual memory larger than physical memory?

Second thing is, Can i change the code to make it little large, Is there any performance benefit If i change the code to expand virtual memory?

Comment: Why are you asking? What do you mean by "making it a little large"?

Answer (score 0):

All the memory management (and [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space)) management code is involved.

From the application point of view, you should understand more [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) (the kernel controls the [MMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) and handles [page faults](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault)), notably the [mmap(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html), [mprotect(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mprotect.2.html), [madvise(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/madvise.2.html), [execve(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html) syscalls. Applications change their address space using these syscalls. You can use the [proc(5)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) filesystem to query about it. For instance `cat /proc/self/maps` is showing the address space of the process executing that `cat`

Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com). Learn more about [VDSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSO) & [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR).

Within the kernel, the relevant source code is mostly its [mm/](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=tree;f=mm;hb=HEAD) subdirectory
(but nearly every filesystem has `mmap` specific code, and page faults are also related to scheduling, etc...)